# Triggers in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have two tables, purchases and sales:

Purchases

```
id->1
product_id->2
quantity_received->10
```

Sales

```
id->1
product_id->2
quantity_sold->5
```

I want a trigger that would create another table Stocks with:

```
id->1
product_id->2
quantity_received->10
quantity_sold->5
amount_remaining->(10-5)
```

Is that possible? And how would i do it? Or is there another way without using triggers

Comment: It is possible to create such trigger. In fact, you need to create 2 triggers for the 2 tables. Although, received and sold volumes are usually not recorded in the stocks table, those are rather calculated in sales / purchases reports for a given period. Stocks table usually just record the current available volume. How to do all these? By writing the appropriate create trigger statements. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I agree with Shadow. What is the use case of the stocks table? Will each product_id have multiple entries in the stocks table? How do you intend to query the stocks table? Would Sales and Purchases occur at the same time? If not how/when do you link them together for the stocks table update?

Are stocks entries allowed to have nil/zero quantity sold or received if the purchase/sales event can fire independently?

Comment: Thanks Shadow and thun for the help for the help. I created a trigger that created another table(stocks) from the existing tables,still fixing a few issues but am on the right track.